# Is SQLAlchemy autoload thread safe?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is autoload thread-safe? I can't find any document about this.
By the following code,the table can't be loaded successfully(no exception, and no warning or higher log, but table.columns is an empty list) in about first 20ms and then works properly

```
from sqlalchemy import *
import logging
import threading
import time

logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO, format = '%(asctime)s:%(message)s', filename = "autoload_test.log")
logging.getLogger("sqlalchemy").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
engine = create_engine("postgresql://madk@localhost/mydb", echo = False)
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)

lock = threading.Lock()
def load_table():
    while True:
        try:
            table = Table('mytbl', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
            logging.info("size of columns:[%s]", len(table.columns))
        except:
            logging.warn("error occured", exc_info = True)

for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target = load_table)
    t.daemon = False
    t.start()

time.sleep(4)
```

1. with 1 thread: loaded successfully
2. with multi threads without lock protection: all thread loaded
   failed(empty columns) at first 20ms, and then all threads works
   properly
3. with multi threads with lock protection: add thread loaded
   successfully

Comment: Try turning off `t.daemon = False` or add `try ... except Exception as e: logger.exception(e)`to get the actual error message. Now you fail to see it and it is missing from the question. Daemon threads silently eat exceptions.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa thanks, changed as your suggestion, and got same result: no exceptions and no warning or higher level logs, just empty columns list without lock protection under multithread.

Comment: I just ran into this problem and noticed the docs say MetaData is thread-safe for read operations but not necessarily write operations.  Thanks for the locking suggestion, OP. docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData